# How to install cluebringer on 14.04

Tags: postfix, policy

I've done an install of Ubuntu 14.04 on a system which will act as a mail server.  One of the bits I want to install is "Cluebringer" policy daemon.

I can see there are postfix-cluebringer packages, but even after installing these there does not appear to be any daemon or /etc/init.d script.  (But it did install some junk in /usr/share/doc/postfix-cluebringer...)

Googling didn't provide me any immediate insights as to why this might be the case.

Anyone come across this ?   Do I really need to install it from source as I did previously ?